# knitr & xcolor: incompatible color definition

Tags: knitr

I'm using knitr and RStudio to compile LaTeX. In my real project I'd like to use some options from the LaTeX package 'xcolor', but when I do include `\usepackage[options]xcolor`, I get the error message "Incompatible color definition on line xx" where "line xx" corresponds to knitrout blocks. I note that knitr emits `\usepackage[]{color}` to the .tex file, and if I change that to xcolor, all is well. But, I have a bigger project.

Here's a minimal example .Rnw file in which I try to use a named color for url links:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}

\definecolor{Sepia}{named}{Sepia}

% hyperref setup:
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
linkcolor=red,%
urlcolor=Sepia,%
plainpages=false,%
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

<<setup, cache=FALSE, include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
# Global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(keep.source=TRUE, fig.align='center')
@

A quick example. I like \texttt{knitr}: \url{http://yihui.name/knitr/}.

And now for some boring input and output.

<<quickexample>>=
sessionInfo()
x <- rnorm(100, 1, 0)
mean(x)
sd(x)

sessionInfo()
@

\end{document}
```

I've tried using the `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` workaround I've seen in other posts on xcolor, but to no avail.

Although this minimal example does give me a .pdf with sepia coloured links, but in the bigger project, the reams of incompatible color warnings makes it hard to find other LaTeX errors that I need to fix. (So I'm after cleaner log files, I guess.)

Comment: This is something that I'm not satisfied either, and I think I will fix it at some point. A similar question was asked here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knitr/PQG2SnKe_eo/0S_n_Bfm3ZEJ The solution no longer applies, though (you need to substitute `'\\usepackage[]{color}'`). Perhaps you can file a Github issue to me: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues

Answer (score 8):

@Yihui's fix from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knitr/PQG2SnKe_eo/0S_n_Bfm3ZEJ) solved the problem for me:

```
knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {sub('\\usepackage[]{color}', '\\usepackage{xcolor}', x, fixed = TRUE)})
```

Ps.: I've also raised an [issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1068) to that effect, as @Yihui requested.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and @Yihui's fix did not resolve it. I found a solution by modifying the fix by adding the **table** option to the xcolor package (see the [xcolor documentation](https://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/noncvs/docs/xcolor/xcolor.pdf)) and correcting for subsequent errors using comments from this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1384).

The solution that I found is as follows:

1. First, in the preamble, add the packages that you wish to use from the kableExtra package. Omit the **xcolor** package.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{booktabs}`
   ```
2. Next, disable kableExtra from autoloading packages before calling in the library.

   ```
   options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE 
   library(kableExtra)
   ```
3. Finally, use the solution above but add in the table option.

   ```
   knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {sub('\\usepackage[]{color}', `\\usepackage[table]{xcolor}', x, fixed = TRUE)})`
   ```